# JS CORS complaint when loading modules

Tags: javascript, cors, es6-modules

I have a page on the main domain [www.main.com](http://www.main.com) that has a subdomain in an iframe:

```
<body>
  <iframe src="https://subdomain.main.com/" id="iframe"></iframe>
</body>
```

The subdomain has the following JS in the head:

```
function loadModules() {

    const {init} = await import('https://www.main.com/script.js');  
    
}
            
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
                
                loadModules();  
});
```

This should load a script from [www.main.com](http://www.main.com) and in fact it does 90% of the time, but 10% of the time Safari complains with:

```
[Error] Origin https://subdominan.main.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 401
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://subdominan.main.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 401 (https://www.main.com/main.js, line 0)
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Cross-origin script load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.
    (anonymous function) 
    asyncFunctionResume
    (anonymous function)
    promiseReactionJobWithoutPromise
    promiseReactionJob
```

CORS is setup on both sides to allow access from all subdomain i.e :

```
    SetEnvIf Origin ^(https?://.+\.main\.com(?::\d{1,5})?)$   CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=$1
Header append Access-Control-Allow-Origin  %{CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN}e   env=CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN
```

I have no idea why the problem comes and goes, and always if I reload the page the problem goes away again for a while.

Answer (score 0):

The 401 error was the clue, main.com has Basic Authorisation on it and when that is turned of the problem goes away. Not sure why Safari is doing this on and off though.